# How do I check if one string contains characters from another string?

Tags: java, string

I want to create a boolean method that allows me to check if the characters in one string randomly generated in a method before contains characters from a string that the user inputs.

Example:

Random base word: Cellphone

User word: Cell --> Yes this is okay.

User word: Cells --> No, it contains letters not found in original word given.

I'm thinking we can maybe do something that looks like this:

```
public static class boolean usesSymbolsFromWord(String candidate, String base) {
  //pseudocode

  characters in String candidate are found in String base
  return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the available methods in the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?(Hint: one is called `contains`)...

Comment: @assylias - I would rather use a for loop. He will have to sue `contains()` on each *single character String*. For example 'pll` should return `true.`

Comment: check for examples on contains() method of String class, that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Just try it with a build in method of `Java.lang.String`:

```
base.contains(candidate);
```

That's all.

For further informations see the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> contains(CharSequence s)
>   Returns true if and only if this string
>   contains the specified sequence of char values.

Answer (score 1):

try this func

```
boolean allS1CharsAreInS2(String s1, String s2) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        char c = s1.charAt(i);
        if (s2.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without using arrays?

Comment: 1) you can use for(int i =0; i < s1.length(); i++) {char c = s1.charAt(i)

Comment: 2) loop is because i assume you need to check all characters in any order

Comment: I changed my func, take a look

Answer (score 0):

I normally use : `word1.toUpperCase().contains(word2.toUpperCase())` as I prefer case insensitive check. But its based on your requirement. If it has to be case sensitive checking, you can use `word1.contains(word2)`